# Resolve file name on url redirect

Tags: nsis, wininet

I use `wininet` (with an nsis plugin called `inetc`) to download a file.

I want to save the file with the same file name that is used in the url for example `http://some.domain.com/myfile.doc` should be saved as `myfile.doc`. The problem is when I have a url with redirection. For example I can get  `http://some.domain.com/` which redirects to `http://some.domain.com/myfile.doc`, and I want to save it as `myfile.doc`.

How do I tackle this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33647630/nsis-inetc-get-can-i-make-the-downloaded-file-a-variable  This is helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INetC was not really designed to support that but I guess you could call `INetC::head` in a loop and parse the returned header until it is no longer a redirect...

**Edit:**

Since INetC is only designed to deal with files named by the caller it just relies on the high-level WinInet default handling.

While it might be possible to modify INetC or create a new plugin, it might be less work to just have the server do the work. It could return the content-disposition header that INetC::head can download or a special URL like server.com/?getname that just returns the name so you grab the name first with INetC::get and then perform the real INetC::get with the correct destination filename...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it but I don't get anything related to redirection in the headers - can you elaborate? this is an example of headers I'm getting: `HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
ETag: "985a0576bbccd1:0"
Last-Modified: Tue, 06 Nov 2012 22:09:08 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Content-Length: 453112
Date: Thu, 08 Nov 2012 20:41:03 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
` ... I actually just checked it with wireshark and it looks like `inetc::head` is still doing all the re-directions.

Comment: WinINet has both HTTP_QUERY_CONTENT_LOCATION and INTERNET_FLAG_NO_AUTO_REDIRECT but I guess INetC does not expose a way to use them

Comment: It doesn't expose but that doesn't mean I can't expose them :) Thanks for the pointers, with them I also got to `INTERNET_OPTION_URL`. I will add this functionality to inetc and publish it on the thread in nsis forum (if it will solve my problem, of course).