# NSIS Inetc get: can I make the downloaded file a variable?

Tags: nsis

The code is working when I have File_1234.exe added there. But the file name changes and download.php redirects to the exe. So instead of having a fixed file name there, I would like to have a code where i don't need to specify file name.

Is it possible to replace the first File_1234.exe with code to download whatever file the URL gives, and therefore to replace the second File_1234.exe with code that would run (ExecShell) this downloaded file?? Thanks

The code itself is here:

```
Section "File"
inetc::get "http://example.com/download.php" "$pluginsdir\File_1234.exe"
Pop $0
DetailPrint "Result: $R0"
    ExecShell "" '"$pluginsdir\File_1234.exe"'
SectionEnd
```

Answer (score 1):

INetC does not have a flag that passes the INTERNET_FLAG_NO_AUTO_REDIRECT flag to WinInet so there is no way to do a head request and find the location when the server returns a 30x redirection code.

If you can modify download.php to just return the final URL as a small text file when a special parameter is present then you can make two GET requests, the first to get the name and the second to do the main download:

```
Section

InitPluginsDir
StrCpy $0 "http://example.com/download.php?fileid=1234"
inetc::get /SILENT "$0&locationonly=1" "$PluginsDir\location.txt" /END
FileOpen $1 "$PluginsDir\location.txt" R
FileRead $1 $2
FileClose $1
StrLen $1 $2
loop:
    IntOp $1 $1 - 1
    StrCpy $3 $2 1 $1
    StrCmp $3 '/' 0 +4
        IntOp $1 $1 + 1
        StrCpy $3 $2 "" $1
        Goto +2
    StrCmp $3 "" 0 loop
StrCmp $3 "" nofilename
inetc::get "$0" "$PluginsDir\$3" /END
Goto done
nofilename:
MessageBox mb_iconstop "Unable to parse filename from $2"
done:

SectionEnd
```

This example assumes that http://example.com/download.php?fileid=1234 would download the file but http://example.com/download.php?fileid=1234&&locationonly=1 would only return a URL like http://example.com/myfiles/whatever.exe

Comment: Hi, i am having trouble with this: "If you can modify download.php to just return the final URL as a small text file when a special parameter is present" .. How to solve it? thanks!!!!

Comment: @hasani You need to modify the php file on the server.

Comment: yes i understood, but i tried some code and it didn't do anything .. maybe you can tell me what code should i put into the php file on server? thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1):

This is a 5 year later answer to help who ever might want to know how to get inetc::get output into a variable ;)
Obviously you found a solution since then... anyway:

inetc::get has a nice option `/TOSTACK` that does this.

Here's how on your example:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh

Section "File"
inetc::get /TOSTACK "http://example.com/download.php" ""
Pop $0
DetailPrint "Result: $0"
${If} $0 == 'OK'
    Pop $0
    StrCpy $filename $0 
    inetc::get /TOSTACK "http://example.com/$filename" "$PluginsDir\$filename"
    Pop $0
    ${If} $0 == 'OK'
        ExecShell "" '"$pluginsdir\$filename"'
    ${Else}
        MessageBox MB_OK "Cannot download file $filename"
    ${EndIf}
${Else}
    MessageBox MB_OK "Cannot fetch filename to download"
${EndIf}
```

SectionEnd

Answer (score 0):

This is possible if your "http://example.com/download.php" returns URL of file to download.
What I mean: download.php returns URL as text ("http://example.com/file_12345.exe").

1) This text is downloaded with inetc to some local file and read into variable.
2) Use Inetc to download the file from URL (specified in variable) again as a resulting .exe file.

Is this acceptable for you?

Comment: Yes, that could be one option. Can you please share, thanks

Comment: @hasani This means modifying the server and first downloading a small file that contains the final URL that you can then download after locally parsing the string to find the filename...

Comment: Any link or tip where to start would be helpful... i googled for hours before posting this question, and i went through all the nsis and inetc commands but didn't find a solution of a kind

Comment: @hasani Is it your server and can you modify download.php?

Comment: yes, i am on a shared hosting but i can do anything on cpanel, and edit the php